# Determine Whether $\int_1^\infty \frac{x^\frac{2}{3}+x^\frac{5}{3}}{x^2}dx$ diverges or converges

Tags: integration

Yo, dealing with a particularly tricky integral right now. $\int_1^\infty \frac{x^\frac{2}{3}+x^\frac{5}{3}}{x^2}dx$. I want to know if it converges/diverges using the comparison theorem. Which function should I base off the comparison from? I can do something like $\frac{1}{x^\frac{4}{3}}$ for convergence and $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ for divergence. That's all I have figured out for now.

Comment: If $ \ \int_1^\infty \ x^{-1/3} \ dx \ $ diverges, is it really going to matter whether the integral for the other term converges? Your integrand is larger than the integrand of an improper integral which diverges by the " $ \ p-$ test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{x^\frac{2}{3}+x^\frac{5}{3}}{x^2}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{x^\frac{2}{3}+x^\frac{5}{3}}{x^2} = \frac {1}{x^\frac 43} + \frac {1}{x^\frac 13}$$
$$\frac {1}{x^\frac 43} + \frac {1}{x^\frac 13} > \frac {1}{x^\frac 13}$$

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac {1}{x^\frac 13}dx = [\frac 32 x^{2/3}]_1^\infty{\to \infty} $$
Since, $\int_1^{\infty} \frac {1}{x^\frac 13}dx$ diverges, the given integral also diverges.

Comment: You have not shown that the integral diverges.